# Kubernetes Network Issue

Tags: curl, networking, kubernetes, kube-proxy, coredns

I have an issue setting up my Kubernetes Cluster on my Ubuntu 16.04 machines, I have correctly set up a:

1. master node (Machine IP: 10.10.1.122)
2. worker node (Machine IP: 10.10.1.38)

into a cluster with this information:

```
    NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/coredns-86c58d9df4-78lnp                1/1     Running   0          80m
pod/coredns-86c58d9df4-lw7vl                1/1     Running   0          80m
pod/etcd-di-linux-host                      1/1     Running   0          111m
pod/kube-apiserver-di-linux-host            1/1     Running   0          110m
pod/kube-controller-manager-di-linux-host   1/1     Running   0          111m
pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-6wvkh             1/1     Running   0          109m
pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-p7ftb             1/1     Running   0          110m
pod/kube-proxy-rbfvz                        1/1     Running   0          109m
pod/kube-proxy-zwr7b                        1/1     Running   0          111m
pod/kube-scheduler-di-linux-host            1/1     Running   0          111m
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-79ff88449c-9f8qw   1/1     Running   0          89m

NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   111m
service/kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.98.188.215   <none>        443/TCP         89m

NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                     AGE
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64     2         2         2       2            2           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64     110m
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm       0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm       110m
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64     0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm64     110m
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le   0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=ppc64le   110m
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-s390x     0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=s390x     110m
daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                2         2         2       2            2           <none>                            111m

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/coredns                2/2     2            2           111m
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard   1/1     1            1           89m

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/coredns-86c58d9df4                2         2         2       111m
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-79ff88449c   1         1         1       89m
```

My cluster information

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.10.1.122:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://10.10.1.122:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

My Pods

```
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
guids-68898f7dc9-c65nv   1/1     Running   0          102m
Name:               guids-68898f7dc9-c65nv
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               gmf.com/10.10.1.38
Start Time:         Sun, 16 Dec 2018 15:43:41 +0200
Labels:             pod-template-hash=68898f7dc9
                    run=guids
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.244.1.15
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/guids-68898f7dc9
Containers:
  guids:
    Container ID:   docker://125ceccad4e572b514538292aaeaa55e22050c5e9129f834de8e01dfd452c6c1
    Image:          alexellis2/guid-service:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://alexellis2/guid-service@sha256:17207f799760ccdccd0fa1e7f37838af5df915a33f9f27e97951a6eeee8c3a6f
    Port:           9000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 16 Dec 2018 15:43:46 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-hnwtc (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-hnwtc:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-hnwtc
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

The issue I am facing in here that whenever I want to curl the service or the pod IP from the master node it never hits, at the same time curling the service/pod from the worker node goes fine, I am a newbie to Kubernetes but I can't find any lead how I can diagnose this issue, any help would be much appreciated.

when I try to curl the exposed service even I got this result from the master:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
guids        ClusterIP   10.97.160.160   <none>        9000/TCP   92m
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    139m
ubuntu@master:/$ curl http://10.97.160.160:9000/guid
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.97.160.160 port 9000: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

The pod IP which is accessible from other nodes and the clusterIP is accessible from pods inside the kubernetes cluster.

ClusterIP of the service is not a IP address of the pod, it is a virtual address mapped to the pod's IP address based on the rules defined in the service and it is managed by the `kube-proxy` daemonset in kubernetes cluster.

ClusterIP is specifically desired for the communication inside the cluster to access the pods behind the service without caring the how many replicas of the pods are present or on which node pod is present and clusterIP is static unlike pod's IP.

If can read about how service IP works in [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies)

I would like you to follow some debugging steps:

You can check that your service name resolves to ClusterIP from inside the pod using:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod_name> bash
nslookup  <svc_name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

The above command will give you clusterIP of your service.

Check your worker node is pingable from your master node, if it is not then you have some issue with your overlay network, in your case it is flannel.

Comment: Agreed with this Prafull Ladha's answer. Furthermore if you want to curl the exposed service you could use a NodPort (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport). Simply update the service and use that nodePort to access the service.

Comment: Thanks, @Prafull, i tried to run the above command in order to run commands inside the pod and there is the issue

kubectl exec -it guids-68898f7dc9-vlrsn bash
Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.10.1.38:10250: i/o timeout
Pinging worker node from master it goes fine
ubuntu@master:~$ ping 10.10.1.38
PING 10.10.1.38 (10.10.1.38) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.1.38: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.267 ms
@ HansikaMadushanWeerasena also ive tried to curl POD IP from master node not externally without any success

Comment: Could you please check your kubelet logs, is it getting restarted again and again? what are kubelet logs saying, 10250 is a kubelet port. Check kubelet logs using: ` journalctl -xfe -u kubelet`

Comment: @PrafullLadha `master kubelet[7433]: I1216 15:28:39.205823    7433 server.go:137] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250`
there was an issue before with coredns it was doing CrashLoopBackoff but i resolved it as a workaround , the pod it self is running correctly from worker node

Comment: kubelet logs are huge, you must be getting something more, could you fetch some kubelet logs in a file and attach in the question itself.